# How to install script language documentation locally for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vbscript, wsh, jscript

I can only find documentation of VBScript, JScript and the Windows API scripting support (WScript etc.) online. No matter what I install locally, apparently it's not the documentation set that includes the mentioned topics. What do I need to do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standalone documentation on Windows Script 5.6 is available in Microsoft Download Center:
[Windows Script 5.6 Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2764)

<s>As for the VS 2012 docs, I believe Windows Script docs are part of the **Web Development** docs, just like in the online MSDN library.</s>

> (1) the docs are for WSH version 5.6 while WSH for Windows7 is in version 5.8 already

WSH 5.8 is pretty much the same as 5.6. As per these topics:

- [VBScript Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y7bh5(v=vs.84).aspx)
- [JScript Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz(v=vs.84).aspx)

VBScript didn't get any new language features since v. 5.6. JScript 5.8 introduced a few new language features (such as the `JSON` object), but they are only used for JavaScript execution in Internet Explorer and not in WSH:

> Starting with JScript 5.8, by default, the JScript scripting engine supports the language feature set as it existed in version 5.7. This is to maintain compatibility with the earlier versions of the engine.

So, the standalone WSH 5.6 docs are mostly the same as the online MSDN version.

Comment: +1 thanks! :-) the referenced docs are a [.chm] compiled help file and works fine as stand-alone docs. Problems: (1) the docs are for WSH version 5.6 while WSH for Windows7 is in version 5.8 already, and (2) re "Web development", yeah I thought so also but I don't find that doc set, except the likewise named one under "patterns and practices", which I already have and which doesn't contain the scripting docs. :-(

Comment: I'm marking this as "solution" since nobody's come up with a way to get the documentation into the VS 2012 help. Using the standard-alone documentation is perhaps the closes one can come.